# Styles are not loaded with webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I can't get my css to work with webpack css/scss loader. This is part of my config:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {loader: 'style-loader'},
                {loader: 'css-loader'},
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                {loader: 'style-loader'},
                {loader: 'css-loader'},
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                        includePaths: ['./src'],
                    }},
            ],
        },
        ...
```

As far as I know, this will load any `.scss` file from any subfolder inside the `./src` location. So I have the following file in `src/components/foo/styles.scss`:

```
body {
  background-color: green;
}
```

And it doesn't work. What's wrong here? Do you need any more details?

Answer (score 0):

You need an index.js file somewhere with a `require()` statement that loads in your .scss/.css files. Webpack works by loading up all of the *javascript* dependencies in your app so you need to bootstrap that process.

I believe you also need to use the `ExtractTextPlugin` to convert the .scss to CommonJS (couldn't tell you more here, unfortunately).

For reference, here is my `index.js` (in the same directory as `app.scss`):

```
require('./app.scss')
```

and a partial `webpack.config.js` (I left out the entry stuff and output configs):

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")
...
var config = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        // sass
        {test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: [{
                    loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader"
                }]
            })
        },
        // for any images in your scss
        {test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
        }
      ]
   },

   entry: [...],

   plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin("../styles/css/[name].css")
   ]
}

module.exports = config
```